# Data Nucleus error: Class "has application-identity and no objectid-class specified yet has 0 primary key fields"

Tags: java, jpa, datanucleus

I am receiving an error when my JPA code is invoked and the EntityManagerFactory is being retrieved:

```
Caused by: org.datanucleus.metadata.InvalidClassMetaDataException: Class com.analytics.jpa.model.Providers has application-identity and no objectid-class specified yet has 0 primary key fields. Unable to use SingleFieldIdentity.
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.AbstractClassMetaData.determineObjectIdClass(AbstractClassMetaData.java:1415)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.ClassMetaData.populate(ClassMetaData.java:209)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager$1.run(MetaDataManager.java:2806)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.populateAbstractClassMetaData(MetaDataManager.java:2800)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.populateFileMetaData(MetaDataManager.java:2623)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.initialiseFileMetaDataForUse(MetaDataManager.java:1183)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadPersistenceUnit(MetaDataManager.java:1046)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.initialiseNucleusContext(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:855)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.initialise(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:470)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.<init>(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:428)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:116)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:152)
```

My model class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROVIDERS")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "PROVIDERS_SEQ", sequenceName = "PROVIDERS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
public class Providers {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PROVIDERS_SEQ")
     @Column(name = "PROVIDER_ID")
     private Long providerId;

     @Column(name = "PROVIDER_NAME", nullable = false, length = 1000)
     private String providerName;

     @OneToOne(optional = false, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
             fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "provider", targetEntity = Maps.class)
     private Maps map;

     // ... Getters and Setters ...
 }
```

The research that I've done says this error occurs if you do not have a Primary Key field specified, however, my code does.  What else am I missing?

**EDIT**

A few additional items from the DataNucleus.MetaData logs on DEBUG:

> Class "com.analytics.jpa.model.Providers" has been specified with JPA annotations so using those.
>
> Ignoring metadata for field com.analytics.jpa.model.Providers.providerId since we already have MetaData for the property com.analytics.jpa.model.Providers.providerId
>
> Populating all MetaData ...
>
> Class "com.analytics.jpa.model.Providers" : Populating Meta-Data
>
> Class com.analytics.jpa.model.Providers has application-identity and no objectid-class specified yet has 0 primary key fields. Unable to use SingleFieldIdentity.

**EDIT 2**

I am using the following versions of Data Nucleus libraries:

- datanulceus-core: <strike>3.2.5</strike> 4.0.0-release
- datanucleus-api-jpa: <strike>3.2.4</strike> 4.0.0-release
- datanucleus-rdbms: <strike>3.2.4</strike> 4.0.0-release

This is running in Jetty 7.6.7 on JDK 1.7.0_25 on Windows 7

Comment: perhaps (some of) your annotations are not javax.persistence. Look at the log which tells you way more

Comment: Thanks for the response Neil.  I did check the imports and they are all javax.persistence.  The logs didn't give me much more information.  I'll add it to the question, though, in case it helps.

Comment: Does Maps entity have an @Id?

Comment: Yes, Maps entity does have javax.persistence.Id on its primary key as well.  It is defined the same as Providers above.

Comment: perhaps use 4.x? it seems to have more logging/error traps etc, and is a year+ later than what you use there

Comment: I upgraded to 4.0.0-release and still have the same error and no additional logging

Comment: So generate a testcase using their templates http://www.datanucleus.org/documentation/problem_reporting.html There is nothing else that can be answered here with the superficial info that a forum provides